# What are your favourite FxCop rules?

Tags: c#, .net, fxcop

Which FxCop rules do you most value? Which rules highlight the best .Net gotchas?

Answer (score 4):

My favorite FxCop rules are the ones that don't give me errors when compiling my code.

Comment: My favourite FxCop rules are the ones that DO give me errors when compiling my code. Otherwise, what's the point? :)

Answer (score 2):

> Which FxCop rules do you most value?

The one I am going to write to stop developers from using #defines instead of configuration ([Quote needed: Preprocessor usage is bad OO practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473354/quote-needed-preprocessor-usage-is-bad-oo-practice)). 
And I like almost all of the design rules.

Answer (score 2):

I find some of the usage and design rules particularly helpful. I can never remember the details of how to implement the IDisposable or ISerializable interfaces, so I appreciate the gentle reminders from rules like these:

- [Implement IDisposable correctly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms244737.aspx)
- [Disposable fields should be disposed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms182328.aspx)
- [Call GC.SuppressFinalize correctly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms182269.aspx)
- [Implement ISerializable correctly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms182342.aspx)
- [Implement serialization constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms182343.aspx)
- [Mark ISerializable types with SerializableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms182350.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The ones I value the most, and which highlight the gotchas, are the Performance rules.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a FxCop rule but NDepend [Code Query Language rule](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL), but nevertheless, I love the CQL rule:

```
// <Name> Make sure refactored and added methods are covered by tests</Name>
WARN IF Count > 0 In SELECT METHODS WHERE 
PercentageCoverage < 100
AND (CodeWasChanged OR WasAdded)
```