# Initialize all the variables of a specific type to a specific default value in C++

Tags: c++, default-value

In my code i have `int`s, `bool`s, `pointer`s and so on, i also have some type defined by me with `typedef`, how can i manage the default value initialization like it happens in the objects with the contrunctor?

I want to be sure that

```
T var;
```

if untouched, is always equal to my default value and i like to do this without parsing each line of code anche changing the default value manually and without using a preprocessor macro.

is this possible?
for a new `typedef` is possible to define a default value?

Comment: A typedef doesn't create a new type, it just creates an alias for an existing type.

Comment: Okay, I'll bite. *Why* don't you want to use a constant/preprocessor macro? This is the exact use case they were designed for.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan it's basically a problem about the nature and the feature of this macros, if i wrote `#define N 5` somewhere i can't be sure that `N = 5` in my code because this can be easily overwritten. also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473354/quote-needed-preprocessor-usage-is-bad-oo-practice

Comment: if `T` is your type just add that in the constructor, otherwise you can use wrapping like Xeo said....

Comment: @ted my main interest is in the primitive types.

Comment: If you hate the preprocessor that much, why not use a named constant, e.g. `const int MY_VALUE = 12345;`?

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan i hate nothing, it's just the fact that it does not offer a good feature for some critical aspect like the initialization. the const is just another type, i can't use a type to solve a specific issue that i have with another type, this is a dirty solution.

Comment: A constant isn't a type, it's a value, and it's the appropriate solution to your problem. Nobody's going to go around changing your initializations behind your back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++11, you could write `T var{};` to get value initialization to the default value.

In C++03, you could write a non-POD wrapper, whose default constructor will get called by `T var;`:

```
template<class T>
struct default_initializer{
  default_initializer() : value() {}
  default_initializer(T const& v) : value(v) {}
  T value;
};

// somewhere in code
default_initializer<T> var; // calls default ctor and initializes 'value'
                            // to its default value
```

This will allow you to safely default initialize even primitive , POD and aggregate types, which are normally left uninitialized by the `T var;` declaration.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible for primitive types since they don't have a constructor. primitive types which are declared in the context of a function scope are not initialized by default and contain garbage. primitive variables which are declared in the global scope as global variables are always initialized to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this for `int`s, `bool`s, pointers and other primitive data types without having to write some additional code whenever you declare values of such types. But for instances of your custom classes, there is.